# Use dplyr::rename with variable

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, rlang

I have a variable `column` that I'd like to use to rename a column in my table:

```
column <- sym("string")
```

```
tibble(
  a = 1
) %>%
  rename(column = 1)
```

But this outputs the literal column, and I'd like to rename the column "string". I've tried using `!!` but this does not work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

We don't need a symbol here.  Even string should work

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(a =1) %>% 
   rename(!! column := 1)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  string
#   <dbl>
#1      1
```

Or with `rename_at`

```
tibble(a = 1) %>%
  rename_at(1,  ~ as.character(column))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  string
#   <dbl>
#1      1
```

Or the `tibble` can be directly named

```
tibble(!! column := 1)
```